# PHP Booking system database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm fairly new to php and databases, i have created a booking system using xampp. i have a log in page for users to book and a restrict access page for admin to view all of the bookings that have been made. however i cannot seem to view all the bookings that have been made by everyone only the bookings that have been made by the user. I'm sure it is something to do with the session but unsure which part. help would be appreciated.

here is the following recordset code which displays only the user who has logged ins booking and not all of the databases booking.

thank you

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) :     mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Userid'])) {
$colname_Recordset1 = $_SESSION['MM_Userid'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_myconnectiono, $myconnectiono);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE user_id = %s",     GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $myconnectiono) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);


?>
```

Comment: You might consider using a framework for something like this. I personally like CodeIgniter. It will help avoid messy database code such as yours...

Answer (score 2):

Your query limits it to one user only.

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE user_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
```

Where is says `WHERE user_id = %s` will limit the results to only that user's results. Remove that and you will get all of the bookings.

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM booking";
```

You probably will want to improve that query by ordering the results by user, date, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE user_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
```

To:

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM booking", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
```

By removing the `WHERE user_id = %s` all the rows in the bookings table will be returned.